# UIAccessibility in gridView - doesn't see new cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, voiceover, uiaccessibility

In my project I have tableView, as a row there is a custom UITableViewCell, that has one of it property - GMGridView (its similar to a UICollectionView), it has its delegate methods:

```
- (GMGridViewCell *)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
GMGridViewCell *cell = [gridView dequeueReusableCell];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[GMGridViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
        cell.contentView = [[GridViewContentView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame style:GridViewStyleNews];
     }
    Item *feed = _contentArray[index];
       GridViewContentView *contentView = (GridViewContentView *)cell.contentView;
           contentView.textLabel.text = feed.textLabel;
    [contentView.imageView setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:feed.imageLink] withPreset:self.preset];
    cell.contentView = contentView;
    NSLog(@"Address index %d - %p:", index, cell);
        return cell;
}
```

At this stage - created custom contentView  -GridViewContentView and is identities as cells contentView.

This custom content view is defined as Accessible inside of it there are next methods:

```
 - (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement {
    return YES;
}

- (NSString *)accessibilityLabel {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p, %@", self.superview, self.textLabel.text];
}
```

In my case I have 19 items in GridView.

So when the tableView is loaded on iPad(in landscape) created 6 items they are inserted into NSArray inside of GridView:

```
2016-08-07 17:04:39.626 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 0 - 0x7a0162e0:
2016-08-07 17:04:39.632 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 1 - 0x797390e0:
2016-08-07 17:04:39.633 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 2 - 0x79643db0:
2016-08-07 17:04:39.639 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 3 - 0x7a013290:
2016-08-07 17:04:39.640 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 4 - 0x7a0114f0:
2016-08-07 17:04:39.641 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 5 - 0x7965ef30:
```

and Voice over tells correct text - that belongs to taped item. 
But When I scroll - additionally created next 2 items (6 and 7) , and the first 2 - is reused for items (8 and 9).
new items:

```
2016-08-07 17:04:59.961 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 6 - 0x79674ac0:
2016-08-07 17:05:00.366 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 7 - 0x7a074f20:
```

reused items:

```
2016-08-07 17:05:00.982 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 8 - 0x7a0162e0:
2016-08-07 17:05:05.704 DummyAccessibility[2785:230602] Address index 9 - 0x797390e0:
```

After debugging I identified that these newly items are never accepted by UIAccessibility. When I try to tap on it - VoiceOver tells - is redirected inside of the cell (number 5) and takes the textValue from it.
So when I tries to tap on the reused items - it tells correct (reused textInfo). Such a situation (with these new items keeps the even when they are also reused). I can't understand why it is like that.
[image: item number 6 that Voice Over doesn't see]

I spend a lot of time with it, but can't understand why it works like that. I would really appreciate any idea.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I believe you will have to implement it on the `UITableViewCell`, e.g. making it an accessibility container because the cell already generates an accessibility label for you.

Comment: @Sulthan, you mean that the best way is to make a UITableViewCell as a container, and inside of it create an array of _accessibilityElements, and in method "cellForItemAtIndex" create UIAccessibilityElement and put it into the array _accessibilityElements?

Comment: Something like that. Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact solution. I was dealing with this problem years ago when that was needed for UI Automation. Probably you want to make `accessibilityElements` independent on `cellForItem`. It won't be an easy solution. An ideal solution would probably be to leave `UITableView` altogether and use a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: @Sulthan, thank you very much for an advice, I will try to implement it now. Cause I retried a lot of methods - but nothing worked properly....

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129915/custom-uitableviewcell-trouble-with-uiaccessibility-elements

Comment: @Sulthan, its a huge project, and rewrite all - it will be difficult, so i will try at the beginning to deal with the existing situation, if can't manage - will rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on the base of Sean Howell answer here
[iOS Accessibility for CollectionView in a TableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638357/ios-accessibility-for-collectionview-in-a-tableviewcell)

So I added additional property - UIView in my custom tableViewCell,

and then added into it -in my case - GMGridView.

```
    self.trickView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.trickView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.trickView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    _trickView.accessibilityElements = @[gmGridView];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_trickView];
    [self.gridView removeFromSuperview];
    self.gridView = nil;
    self.gridView = gmGridView;
    [self.trickView addSubview:gmGridView];
```